# Activated Ruby gems different that my gem list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redmine

You can see all the problem on

http://redmine.stats.yt/

If you go on the section

```
Activated Ruby gems
```

You can see :

```
rails => 2.3.5
activesupport => 2.3.5
activerecord => 2.3.5
actionpack => 2.3.5
actionmailer => 2.3.5
activeresource => 2.3.5
```

But if i use `gem list`

This is completly different version, don't know why ?

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.0.2, 3.2.16)
actionpack (4.0.2)
activemodel (4.0.2, 3.2.16)
activerecord (4.0.2, 3.2.16)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activeresource (4.0.0, 3.2.16)
activesupport (4.0.2, 3.2.16)
arel (5.0.0, 4.0.1, 3.0.3)
atomic (1.1.14)
bigdecimal (1.2.5)
builder (3.2.2, 3.1.4, 3.0.0)
bundler (1.5.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
coderay (1.1.0)
daemon_controller (1.1.8)
erubis (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.1)
gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
```

Comment: Can you post your gemfile? You may have the wrong gem version listed on the gemfile. Basically passenger is telling that you can't activate actionpack 4.0 when activepack 2.3.5 is active. Try running this in the console `gem uninstall actionpack -v '2.3.5'` and let us know what you get. It's weird that when you run gem list, you aren't seeing 2.3.5 as an installed version on actionpack, but try uninstalling all the gem with version 2.3.5, and re-install all the gems at the version you wish them to be at

Comment: <code>gem uninstall actionpack -v '2.3.5'
INFO:  gem "actionpack" is not installed</code>

Comment: hmmmmm, let me look up something. this is weird.

Comment: @MikeLegacy not weird, this is ruby...

Comment: True, ruby is a little bitch.

Comment: Are you using anything like `rvm` or `rbenv`?

Comment: i use rvm yes, this is more simple to install ruby, there is a link ?

Comment: when you run `gem list`, rails isn't showing up in your installed gems. Why is this? try running this and tell me what you get `rails -v`

Comment: `rails -v
Rails 4.0.2`

Comment: damnit. you are stumping me.

Comment: i think `rvm` can be the problem. @MikeLegacy i find this two line with locate `/var/cache/apt/archives/libactionpack-ruby1.8_2.3.5-1.2+squeeze8_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libactionpack-ruby_2.3.5-1.2+squeeze8_all.deb`

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at these instructions for using RVM with Passenger http://rvm.io/integration/passenger.

It looks like Passenger is running your app with a different Ruby version then you are expecting.

Comment: Passenger is running his app with Ruby 2.1.0 which is the latest stable release. I think you mean it's running a different version of RAILS. Since it's running rails 2.3.5, which is very weird.

Comment: since running `gem list` doesnt show the versions of the gems being reported in the error message my guess is that passenger isn't using RVM at all. It may just be using the system ruby version.